# Where do I go to purchase unlocked characters?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

In *LEGO: Harry Potter Years 5-7*, where in the Diagon Alley area to you go to purchase unlocked characters?  I have only been able to find the store where you purchase new spells and the location in the bar where you can view movies and purchase unlockable red bricks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to go to Madam Malkin's Robes for All Occasions to purchase characters.

Comment: Where is that in relation to the store where you purchase new spells?  I swear I've walked up and down Diagon Alley and not found an entrance, but I was tired last night...

Comment: It should be right nearby. Mind you, I am playing the DS version which works differently, I only know the above from talking to  someone else playing a console version, so I might be wrong. I know that is the shop you need, though.

Comment: @Jason If you go further down the street (away from the camera) there is a building on the left side that you can enter. That's where you buy characters.

Comment: @Adeese Thank you. I was wracking my brain trying to figure out where he had to go.

Comment: @AshleyNunn - You don't carry your DS with you everywhere you go?!?

Comment: @JasonBerkan I do, actually - but this area isn't in the DS version.